# Getting data from Yahoo Finance

Tags: yahoo-finance, yql, stockquotes

I read about the YQL, but I didn't understand how can I get some simple data (like company ticker, market cap, stock price, etc.), for ALL COMPANIES?

And an additional question, how can I get all Yahoo Finance tables and theirs fields that can be queried by YQL?

Comment: Can you really use this data commercially ? I am not sure, read: http://meumobi.github.io/stocks%20apis/2016/03/13/get-realtime-stock-quotes-yahoo-finance-api.html

Answer (score 64):

To your first question, you can't really do any query through YQL to get data for all companies. It's more oriented towards obtaining data for a smaller query. (I.e., it's not going to give you a full data dump of the whole Yahoo! Finance database.)

To your second question, here's how you can get started exploring the Yahoo! Finance tables in YQL:

1. Start at the [YQL Console](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/)
2. In the upper left corner, make sure Show Community Tables is checked
3. Type `finance` in the search field
4. You'll see all the Yahoo Finance tables (about 15)

Then you can try some example queries like the following:

[`select * from yahoo.finance.quote where symbol in ("YHOO","AAPL","GOOG","MSFT")`](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quote%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22YHOO%22%2C%22AAPL%22%2C%22GOOG%22%2C%22MSFT%22)&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys)

*Update 2016-04-04:* Here's a current screenshot showing the location of the Show Community Tables checkbox which must be clicked to see these finance tables:
[image]

Comment: Some change in YQL. Checkbox show community tables to the left.

Comment: @BrianC : But how do you specify the exchange in that? I mean the stock exchange

Comment: The only thing I see under `finance` now is `finance.scrape.trend` which does not give access to the market cap, description, etc...

Comment: @Ashwin You can get the stock exchange by querying the yahoo.finance.quoteslist table.

Here's a query that I am running and works well:

select * from yahoo.finance.quoteslist where symbol in ("^IXIC", "^NYA", ^DJI") &format=json &diagnostic=true &env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys

Make sure you also url encode your query url

Comment: Is there a query will help to collect the prices each hour from the previous day?

Comment: To make it clear, you need to check the "Show community tables" option on the left sidebar to allow access to the `yahoo.finance.*` tables.

Comment: Is there a limit to the number of individual stocks you can request at a single time?

Comment: Here's the [info on usage limits.](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/usage_info_limits.html) Basically its  2000 requests / hour public.  20,000 requests/hour oauth, 100K/day oauth max/day.

Comment: Nope.  Iv'e just been checking for something else, and the YQL console has now been closed down.  All that's left in it's place is a message telling you to bugger off.

Comment: On top of that, they've also closed down vast majority of the community tables too.

Comment: Yea, I would assume that for the parts of YQL that aren't dead yet, it will be soon. There's some good discussion in this [Quora thread](https://www.quora.com/Did-Yahoo-Stock-API-shut-down) about alternatives for Finance APIs.

Answer (score 29):

As from the answer from BrianC use the YQL console.
But after selecting the "Show Community Tables" go to the bottom of the tables list and expand yahoo where you find plenty of yahoo.finance tables:

Stock Quotes:

- yahoo.finance.quotes
- yahoo.finance.historicaldata

Fundamental analysis:

- yahoo.finance.keystats
- yahoo.finance.balancesheet
- yahoo.finance.incomestatement
- yahoo.finance.analystestimates
- yahoo.finance.dividendhistory

Technical analysis:

- yahoo.finance.historicaldata
- yahoo.finance.quotes
- yahoo.finance.quant
- yahoo.finance.option*

General financial information:

- yahoo.finance.industry
- yahoo.finance.sectors
- yahoo.finance.isin
- yahoo.finance.quoteslist
- yahoo.finance.xchange

2/Nov/2017: **Yahoo finance has apparently killed this API**, for more info and alternative resources see https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=15616880

Comment: @rdw any idea why running this query fetches nothing really: https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20yahoo.finance.analystestimate%20WHERE%20symbol%3D'YHOO'&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=

Comment: It seems the calls to yahoo.finance.historical and yahoo.finance.dividendhistory are no longer working. Could it be because these tables are not public anymore?

Comment: @hyprfrcb Yahoo finance has killed this API

Answer (score 10):

Example to recieve it through a request:

a) [http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.historical](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20yahoo.finance.historicaldata%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%27YHOO%27%29%20and%20startDate%20=%20%272009-09-11%27%20and%20endDate%20=%20%272010-03-10%27&diagnostics=true&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys)

OR

b) [http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%22AAPL%22%29&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys)

Answer (score 1):

Since Yahoo Finances API was disabled, I found [Alpha Vantage API](https://www.alphavantage.co/)

This a stock query sample that I'm using with Excel's Power Query:

```
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=15min&outputsize=full&apikey=demo
```

Comment: Have a query regarding calling exhange:symbol via alpha vantage

The following works

https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=NSE:TATAMOTORS&interval=1min&apikey=xxxx works

But the following does not work

https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=NSE:TATAMOTORS&interval=1min&apikey=xxxx

Can you please explain why?

Comment: @KaranBhandari: not sure if it is meant for NSE stocks

Comment: Make sure you have a valid key. According to your link it doesn't. Register won't take up than a minute. Their documentation is really self explanatory step by step.

Comment: Have a valid key,  I thought API keys are secret. Did not share.

Comment: Look at the first link - responding for NSE