# How to get commodity data from yahoo finance?

Tags: yahoo-finance

I am working on a small widget for my projects which basically looks like this. [Futures for Yahoo Finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/futures?t=energy)

How can I get the data for Natural Gas, Gasoline, Crude Oil, Heating Oil and their Change?. I want to retrieve those data via json maybe and create a box widget or a ticker. The Image attached is what I am trying to make. Thank you.

[image]

PS: I tried CLJ15.NYM Symbol for Crude Oil using yahoo.finance.quotes table in the YQL Console, but it did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can type the symbol in the same way you would type in a stock. [Getting data from Yahoo Finance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795726/getting-data-from-yahoo-finance) provides you with a good example of how to use stock symbols with yql.

For those exact 4, it would look like this:

[select * from yahoo.finance.quote where symbol in ("CLK15.NYM", "HOK15.NYM", "NGK15.NYM", "RBK15.NYM")](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20%2A%20from%20yahoo.finance.quote%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%22YHOO%22%2C%22AAPL%22%2C%22GOOG%22%2C%22MSFT%22%29&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys#h=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quote%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22CLK15.NYM%22%2C%20%22HOK15.NYM%22%2C%20%22NGK15.NYM%22%2C%20%22RBK15.NYM%22))

Note: you can use yahoo.finance.quote or yahoo.finance.quotes

Comment: I wonder why it did not work last time, but it works checking on your answer.

Comment: That link has a lot of confusing stuff in it - like two select statements mixed, and triggers an XXS error.  When I go to the Yahoo console, I get this for those selections:  https - query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quote%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22CLK15.NYM%22%2C%20%22HOK15.NYM%22%2C%20%22NGK15.NYM%22%2C%20%22RBK15.NYM%22)&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=

Comment: And here is the link to console, without the other symbols:  https - developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quote%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%22CLK15.NYM%22%2C%20%22HOK15.NYM%22%2C%20%22NGK15.NYM%22%2C%20%22RBK15.NYM%22%29&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys