# Yahoo Finance Current Quotes Error 999 No Definition Found

Tags: yahoo-finance, yahoo-api

Anyone know if current quotes was permanently removed or if this is just a temporary glitch?

The error message embedded in the csv meta data is:

> Sorry, Unable to process request at this time -- error 999

Examples:

- [Getting data from Yahoo Finance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795726/getting-data-from-yahoo-finance)
- [Developer YQL console](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=show%20tables&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys#h=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%22YHOO%22%2C%22AAPL%22%2C%22GOOG%22%2C%22MSFT%22%29)
- [Xml Example](https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22msft%22,%22aapl%22)&diagnostics=true&env=store)

In the Xml Example link, the error message is:

> No definition found for Table yahoo.finance.quote

Tried both `yahoo.finance.quote` and `yahoo.finance.quotes`.

Comment: https://forums.yahoo.net/t5/Known-issues-and-updates/Finance-download-error-999/m-p/387511#M13

Comment: Thank you for finding that. I wonder what the violation was, and why terminating the entire service completely was the chosen solution.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47064776/has-yahoo-suddenly-today-terminated-its-finance-download-api/47148296#47148296 for a workaround.