# How to get Industry Data from Yahoo Finance using Python?

Tags: python, ticker

I currently have some tickers and data from yahoo finance gained through datareader for Python. I have got everything for the dataframe in relation to numbers except the industry from the profile of the ticker. I was wondering if there is any code that would work that would show the industry for the following ticker displayed through the profile page of yahoo?

Code Below:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as pdr

Tickers=['SBUX','TLRY']

SD='2005-01-31'

ED='2018-12-31'

TickerW=pdr.datareader(Tickers,'yahoo',SD,ED)

TickerW.head()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting data from Yahoo Finance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795726/getting-data-from-yahoo-finance)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate as that is using yql not python.

Answer (score 7):

This cannot be done with pandas_datareader see [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/103). You could use [yfinance](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance) instead to get the sector.

as an example try:

```
import yfinance as yf

sbux = yf.Ticker("SBUX")
tlry = yf.Ticker("TLRY")

print(sbux.info['sector'])
print(tlry.info['sector'])
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! Much Appreciated! Just a newbie to coding lol :)

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. This is the Nth time I have to find this out, yahoo kept changing and deprecating their APIs!