# YFinance_Can't get data from dictionary_Python_Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, yfinance

This is my first experience in Python and Stackoverflow :)
I try to update my xls file with Portfolio using Yfinance.
I'm interested in two parameters on each stock : current price and sector.
I try to update my Pandas DataFrame using the code below.
It works fine for the "Price" but I can't extract "Sector" - get an error below.

What I'm doing wrong here?

Well, there is a "sector" key in the dictionary for each stock. I try to update the Excel file, so there isn't much code

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[271], line 7
      5 stock_info = yf.Ticker(ticker).info
      6 price = stock_info['regularMarketPrice']
----> 7 sector = str(stock_info['sector'])
      8 ibkr.loc[i, ['Price of share']] = price
      9 ibkr.loc[i, ['Sector']] = sector

KeyError: 'sector'
```

The code:

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np <br/>  ibkr = pd.read_excel("BKR_WISHLIST.xlsx") <br/> ibkr.columns = ['Company_name', 'Symbol', 'Number of shares', 'Price of share', 'Total_value_share, USD'] <br/> ibkr.dropna(subset=['Total_value_share, USD', 'Number of shares'], inplace=True) <br/> ibkr.insert(2, "Sector", "XXX") <br/> ibkr.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True) <br/>  my_tickers = ibkr["Symbol"].tolist()
tickers = yf.Tickers(my_tickers)
# i = 0
for ticker in my_tickers:
    stock_info = yf.Ticker(ticker).info
    # price = stock_info['regularMarketPrice']
    # sector = stock_info['sector']
    ibkr.loc[i, 'Price of share'] = stock_info['regularMarketPrice']
    #ibkr.loc[i, 'Sector'] = stock_info["sector"]
    i += 1
```

```
    my_tickers = ibkr["Symbol"].tolist()
tickers = yf.Tickers(my_tickers)
i = 0
for ticker in my_tickers:
    stock_info = yf.Ticker(ticker).info
    price = stock_info['regularMarketPrice']
    sector = stock_info['sector']
    ibkr.loc[i, ['Price of share']] = price
    ibkr.loc[i, ['Sector']] = sector
    i = I+1
```

Comment: Can you try like this 
```for ticker in my_tickers:
    stock_info = yf.Ticker(ticker).info
    ibkr.loc[i, "Sector"] = stock_info["sector"]
    ibkr.loc[i, "Price"] = stock_info["regularMarketPrice"]
    i += 1```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But wha't the principal difference? The code is better but it still gives the same error : ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[272], line 9
      6 # price = stock_info['regularMarketPrice']
      7 # sector = stock_info['sector']
      8 ibkr.loc[i, 'Price of share'] = stock_info['regularMarketPrice']
----> 9 ibkr.loc[i, 'Sector'] = stock_info["sector"]
     10 i += 1

KeyError: 'sector'

Comment: Basically, Keyerror states it is not able to find the sector. Can you share a bit more of your code? Or can you check when you are debugging is it able find sector ?

Comment: Well, there is a "sector" key in the dictionary for each stock.

Comment: @twister_void I think that "sector" may be missing in one of the enquiries (I have quite a lot tickers). How can I can skip NA (or fill in with NaN) in my loop?

Comment: @twister_void I meant for Sector. If it's NaN (no value in the string) then fill with "Undefined".

Comment: @twister_void or maybe there isn't even a key "sector" for some of the tickers. Is it possible to skip or fill the gap?

Comment: i added answer to reduce lot of comments hope answer helps if yes then please accept as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you guys for your help!
I don't know how to @ you here, but I hope you will this post.

The problem was that the stock_info for some objects (ETF) did not have a "sector" key.
So with help of @Damian Satterthwaite-Phillips and @twister_void this code did work:

```
my_tickers = ibkr["Symbol"].tolist()
tickers = yf.Tickers(my_tickers)
i = 0
for ticker in my_tickers:
    stock_info = yf.Ticker(ticker).info
    ibkr.loc[i, 'Sector'] = stock_info.get('sector', 'NA')
    ibkr.loc[i, "Price of share"] = stock_info["regularMarketPrice"]
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be a problem with the value in the sector that's why `KeyError` is raised because the value is not found in some case you can handle with loop

```py
for ticker in my_tickers:
    stock_info = yf.Ticker(ticker).info
    ibkr.loc[i, "Sector"] = stock_info["sector"]  
    if stock_info["sector"] is None or stock_info["sector"] == "":
        ibkr.loc[i, "Sector"] = "NA"
    ibkr.loc[i, "Price"] = stock_info["regularMarketPrice"]
    i += 1
```

Comment: This will still raise a `KeyError` if the `sector` key does not exsit.  Replace lines 3-5 with just `ibkr.loc[i, 'Sector'] = stock_info.get('sector', 'NA')`

Answer (score 0):

The `stock_info` object does not have a `sector` key:
For example,

`yf.Ticker('MSFT').info`

returns

`{'regularMarketPrice': None, 'preMarketPrice': None, 'logo_url': ''}`

It looks like it might have had `sector` at one point (e.g.: [How to get Industry Data from Yahoo Finance using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59080447/how-to-get-industry-data-from-yahoo-finance-using-python)), but it may be that Yahoo Finance no longer publishes these data.

Answer (score 0):

The API seems to be broken.  I have tried upgrading yfinance from 1.86 all the way up to 2.x.  Whether I put in a stock ticker or a fund ticker or ETF, I only get back the 3 keys:  {'regularMarketPrice': None, 'preMarketPrice': None, 'logo_url': ''}.  I don't think this is a "sector" problem at all... it seems more like a Yahoo problem... noworky.

Comment: Hello! No, it works just fine. You can check it here: https://github.com/AlefTester/Yfiance_portfolio

Note that there is problem with yFinance and `Ticker` : it doesn't work if yFinance not updated to 0.2.4! update it with `pip install yfinance==0.2.4`